# General Topology - 2-fold Covering map of Mobius strip (with unit circle)

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Given $I=[0,1]$, $S^{1}=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$, and the mobius strip M defined by the relation $(0,t)\sim(1,1-t)$ on $I\times I$, How can I prove that there exists a covering map $p:S^{1}\times I\to M$, such that 
$\forall t\in M: |p^{-1}(t)|=2$ ?

I know that given a covering map p to a connected space B, if there exists $b_0\in B$  such that $|p^{-1}(b_0)|=k$, then p is a k-fold covering of B. (and know how to proove it). So if I were to find (or proove the existence of) a covering map $p:S^{1}\times I\to M$ such that there exist $t\in M: |p^{-1}(t)|=2$, I would be set.

Is this even the right way to approach the question?

Any solutions \ guidance will be of great help.

Comment: Once solved, you might want to try to see if you can produce a cover with any degree (since the fundamental group of the Mobius strip is $\mathbb{Z}$). The intuition is pretty much the same as Carot's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an homeomorphism $S^1\rightarrow [0,2]/(0=2)$ (use for instance polar coordinates on the plane and scale).

Then  $$f:(x,y) \in [0,2]\times I \mapsto (x \text{ }(mod\text{ }1),y) \in I \times I$$ is well defined and induces a continuous function when you quotient on the right.

Since $f(0,t)=f(2,t)$ you get a continuous function $S^1\times I \rightarrow M$ which is the desired covering.

You can also convince yourself geometrically that  you can cover a Moebius strip by a cylinder if you get around it twice.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! what do you mean by (x(mod 1),y)I(\times)I?

Comment: There was a typo. It should be easyer to understand now. Do you have a problem with mod notations ?

Comment: Thank you! No, I do not, but just out of interest, and to make sure I understand correctly, isn't x (mod 1) always 0? If so, what is the advantage of using mod1 notation instead of just writing 0?

Comment: No that's not what it means at all ! Here it is $x$ if $x \in I$ and $x-1$ if $x \in [1,2]$.

Comment: @Carot by $x (mod 1)$ you mean $\lfloor x \rfloor$ (the fractional part of x), right?

Comment: @GuySa The fractional part is usually denoted $\{x\}$ (and the integral part $\floor{x}$) but yes. Here I like the notation mod better since I want to see my elements in the quotient rather than in the real number line.

Answer (score 1):

Picture proof, the squares correspond to the Möbius strip, the arrows show how to identify, the whole rectangle corresponds to circle times interval:

[image: A two cover of [0,1] X Möbius strip]

Comment: Yes much more visual than mine :)

Comment: Your proof is precise! (It is a true map. In the picture one has to imagine the "folding" as a map.) Mine is a visual complement only.